# Сортировка таблицы по дате из связной таблицы SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Никак не могу сообразить как правильно реализовать SQL запрос. Есть две таблицы:
**Employee**(id,fio,adres,.....) и **SIZ**(id, date_start_wear, date_end_wear, employee_id)
Суть такова, есть таблица с сотрудниками и у каждого сотрудника есть список выданного СИЗ (средств индивидуальной защиты). Нужно отсортировать сотрудников по дате окончания носки СИЗ, т.е. первыми тех у кого дата ближе.
Пробовал написать такой запрос:

```
SELECT e.* FROM Employee e, SIZ s 
WHERE s.employee_id = e.id
ORDER BY ABS(now() - s.date_end_wear) DESC
```

В результате на выходе много повторных записей для каждого сотрудника. Помогите разобраться как правильно составить запрос для моего случая.

Если добавить `GROUP BY employee.id`, то выходит ошибка `ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'SIZ.date_end_wear' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by SQL.sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну на самом деле задача гораздо сложнее кажущейся, ибо таблицы не имеют пометки, выданы ли новые СЗ тому, у кого предыдущие выношены. И неясно, а не присутствуют ли записи для СЗ, срок которых буквально завтра истечёт, но на замену уже выданы новые СЗ.

Но если предположить, что ни таких неудачников, ни таких счастливчиков нет, то запрос

```
SELECT e.id
FROM Employee e
JOIN SIZ s ON s.employee_id = e.id
WHERE s.date_end_wear > CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY MIN(s.date_end_wear)
```

вернёт `id` сотрудников в нужном порядке. А если нужны полные сведения, то его надо использовать как подзапрос для отбора записей из другой копии таблицы:

```sql
SELECT Employee.*
FROM Employee 
JOIN ( SELECT e.id, MIN(s.date_end_wear) mindate
       FROM Employee e
       JOIN SIZ s ON s.employee_id = e.id
       WHERE s.date_end_wear > CURRENT_DATE
       GROUP BY e.id ) ee USING (id)
ORDER BY ee.mindate
```

Ну а в MySQL 8+ просто используйте оконную функцию в CTE.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ) вы правы, далее мне нужно будет тоже реализовать выборку по СИЗ который ещё не списан и так же рассмотреть момент где срок носки подошёл к концу. Но надеюсь я справлюсь)